# How to get OnServiceConnected to run?

Tags: android, android-service

I've created a ServiceConnection object called connection.

However, the onServiceConnected method is never called.

Any ideas on how to get it to work? Thanks

Heres my code:

```
public static boolean print(String message){
    if(printerInitialized != true){
        Log.e(TAG,"Unitialized printer. Can't print");
        return false;
    }


    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra("MAC", printerUuid);
    sendIntent.putExtra("DATA", message);
    sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.blueslib.android.app","com.blueslib.android.app.PrintService"));

    context.getApplicationContext().bindService(sendIntent,connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    return true;
}

public static ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Log.e("System.out", "Service Disconnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Log.e("System.out", "Service connected");
    }
};
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Is your service properly declared in the manifest? Also, have you tried with your service's class directly in the intent's constructor? `Intent sendIntent = new Intent(context, PrintService.class);` It is personal opinion, but I find it more maintainable if ever you change a package/component name.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that I had to declare the service in the Manifest. How would I do that?